# How to use addValueEventListener in a first time for Android

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It's very confusing Firebase Database api for Android.

I would like to update some part of `json` objects, but I can't. This is firebase database.

[image]

First of all the user create vocabulary, following this code

```
    /* reference of /vocabulary/{user_id}/*/
    final DatabaseReference vocabularyRef = FBDatabaseReference.getAllVocabulary(user);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(oldName)){
        // if vocabulary renamed remove preview
        vocabularyRef.child(oldName).removeValue();
    }
    // set user vocabulary
    vocabularyRef.child(String.valueOf(userVocabulary.name())).
            setValue(new FBVocabulary(userVocabulary), completionListener);
```

If vocabulary had created successfully user can add words into them. 
But after adding words, user can modify vocabulary `name` or `color` etc.. In that time I lose all words, because the vocabulary object has recreate.

According of Firebase doc for updating a child I should `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` or `addValueEventListener`
When I use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of previews code, User can not create vocabulary.

In firebase documentation written if reference not created yet the snapshot objects is null.

```
    /* reference of /vocabulary/{user_id}/vocabulary3/ */
    final DatabaseReference vocabularyRef = FBDatabaseReference.getAllVocabulary(user).child("vocabulary3");
    vocabularyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Object value = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (value == null){
                dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(new FBVocabulary(userVocabulary), completionListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

In this case each time called `onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)` with **exception: Permission denied.** As far as I understand is is because the reference is `null`.

1. Can I check if reference exist or not ? then update data.
2. How can I use `addValueEventListener` in a first time ?

Comment: what is the code that you tried when using a listener? Also what do you want to get updated? If you are updating `vocabulary1` and `words` node is inside of it, then yes it will be overriden

Comment: @Peter Haddad I would like to update vocabulary data, without words, user words must be not changed

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("vocabulary1");
ref.child("color").setValue(new_value);
ref.child("id").setValue(new_value);
ref.child("footercolor").setValue(new_value);
ref.child("headercolor").setValue(new_value);
//and so on..
```

You can do this, thus updating the values under the node without changing the value of the `word` node.

To check if it exists or not do this:

```
DatabaseReference refs=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("vocabulary").child("key_here").child("vocabulary1");
 refs.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                 //dont do anything
                }
                else{
                     refs.child("color").setValue(new_value);
                      //so on
                    } 
                  }
               });
```

Comment: I agree Peter, It's correct, but user can rename a key, any way I should get a object snapshot, and update. But in that case, user can not create the first. No any way to check if reference exist or not ?

Comment: What do you mean? you want the user to update the random key under `vocabulary` or another key? You want him to update this `kZPOUKw87nQm7nJTbMo0gmzaoGg1`?

Comment: vocabulary1 its the name of vocabulary. User can modify and set another name

Comment: yes that will not work, because  if you changed `vocabulary1` then everything inside it will change also(so words also will change)

Comment: That's why I should get the data from reference, In JS api there are some kind of api, to get data, but for an android I cant find or its not avialble yet

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, That is because of database rules.
depend of this line

```
".read"  : "auth != null && $uid == auth.uid && data.exists()"
```

if `data.exists()` rule added each time `addValueEventListener->onCancelled` method called while data have not created yet.

While without  `data.exists()` rule, `addValueEventListener` returned object `snapshot` and it's null. Then I can create if is null, or update if is not null